# Accessing the class name for search suggestions - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<div class="wizzy-autocomplete-suggestions">
   <ul class="autocomplete-suggestions-list">
      <li class="autocomplete-item-head" data-index="0">
         Categories
      </li>
      <!-- ending of autocomplete-item-head -->
      <li class="autocomplete-item">
         <a data-selectable="true" data-searchterm="dove curls" href="#" class="autocomplete-link" data-index="0">
         <span class="wizzy-autocomplete-label"> <em>dove</em> curls </span>
         <span class="autocomplete-text-wrapper"></span>
         </a><!-- ending of autocomplete-link -->
      </li>
      <!-- ending of autocomplete-item -->
   </ul>
</div>
```

When I search for DOVE in search box, auto suggestions appears as below:

```
                    1. Categories 
                          - Dove curls
                          - Dove hair therapy
                    2.Brands
                         - Dove
                    3.Trending searches
                        - Dove hair mask
                    4.Top products
```

I have tired using xpath, text but always pointing to wrong name or classname